# How can i create AVD for different sizes and densities?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, multiscreen

I am beginner in android programming.
I want to change the program that the program be multi screen. I want to create a few emulator for test my program. I want to create some emulator that check table3 in this link(http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) but i don't know how can i select and fix size of emulator?

I create a emulator with this features.

Name=SmallWithHighQuality / Target= Android 4.1 / Size of sd card=128MB
In Skin section, in opposite resolution, i write  480*640

In Android Virtual Device Manager window, i select start button, and select Scale display to real device, in opposite Screen size, i write 3.
But when i run the program, a emulator opens with greater than screen of my emulator that i'v created. Why?

Do i change Monitor DPI? What should i write instead of Monitor DPI?

Sorry if this is stupid question.

Thanks for advises. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

open AVG manager on the Device Definitions tab click on create new device and then set the name and resolutions as per your need and then at the right side select the density of the pixels you want to set and many more options are there choose as per your need.All the best Mate

Comment: but i have not Device Definition. I think my SDK is older than you.

Comment: Then update it Bro,i don't know whether it is possible to customize AVD with old SDKs or not.